# Python Qt5 - Passing a variable for a mysql query

Tags: python

this is the situation

```
...
import MySQLdb
...
    
    def inside_tabbar_clicked(self, index):
        ...
        if index == 2:  
            self.Open_Cimin_tab(location='mostra')

    def db_Get_Data(self, query=''):
        if query:
            try:
                db = MySQLdb.connect( usual stuff)
                cur = db.cursor()
                cur.execute(query) #### here I get the syntax error
                ...

    def fill_Cimin_Table(self, table: QTableWidget, query):
            data = self.db_Get_Data(query)
            table.setRowCount(0)

    def Open_Cimin_tab(self, location):
            self.this_year = strftime("%Y")
            this_month = strftime("%m") # this is without self since I need it this way in other occurences
            if self.MainTabs_tabWidget.currentIndex() != 1:
                self.MainTabs_tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
                self.fill_Cimin_Table(self.Cimin_table,
                 '''
                 SELECT nome, d1 FROM mostra WHERE anno = '%s' AND mese = '%s' '''%(self.this_year, this_month))'''
```

This work perfectly but if I modify the `SELECT` as shown below

```
 SELECT nome, d1 FROM location WHERE anno = '%s' AND mese = '%s' '''%(location, self.this_year, this_month))
```

I get a mysql syntax error when the query is executed because `FROM location` is translated in `FROM 'mostra'` instead of `FROM mostra` as required by mysql

Any idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the correct solution:
the first variable must be %s and not '%s'.
`SELECT nome, d1 FROM %s WHERE anno = '%s' AND mese = '%s' '''%(location, self.this_year, this_month))`